# MODX override generated link url for specific resource

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, modx, modx-revolution

I have a regular website that uses friendly urls and each page generates another level in the domain url

like: `thadomain.com/level1/level2/thepage.html`

I would like to create some **landing pages**. But I want to collect them in a resources called seo.

my landing page alias is webdesign

so modx produces a url like this:
http://www.cloudtec.ch/seo/webdesign

which is correct and should be like that for all my other pages but I want a special treatment for the `/seo/ folder`.

I am looking for a rewrite rule to remove the `/seo/` from the URL.

http://www.cloudtec.ch/webdesign

i tried to modify the htaccess file of modx with this line

```
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/seo/.*
 RewriteRule ^seo/(.*)$ /$1 [L]
```

but it does not work.

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: Your rewrite rule works. As there is no resource corresponding to http://www.cloudtec.ch/webdesign it does not work as you expect.

Comment: thank you for your response. maybe the rewrite rule is correct. But the problem remains. because I only want to create one resource and that I did create under seo/webdesign. To my understanding rewrite can mask an url or a path. I would like to mask seo. So all the url on my page where there is a /seo/ should be removed but the links still must work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this : go in "Settings" tab of your landing resource, check the "freeze url" checkbox and remove the /seo/ manually.

Comment: this is it. thanks for this very helpful hint. Didn't know that this setting exists in modxs.